# MVC show Multiple Select List in View from ViewBag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox, viewbag

I have stored the list in the ViewBag like this:

```
ViewBag.CarTypes = db.CarTypes.Select(c=>c.Name).ToList();
```

Now, I want to display these names in the List Box so user can select multiple names. I am trying but I always get error.

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.carNames, ViewBag.CarTypes as SelectList)
```

It is not working. What am I doing wrong? Is it right approach?

I know ViewBag is weakly typed and I should not use it, Instead I should use view models but I need to use ViewBag.

Comment: did my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you list box to this:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model=>model.carNames, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.CarTypes))
```